# Unity 3D Spring joint textures

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello i'm doing a simple 3d game and wanted to make something like a grappling hook and it all works perfectly, but i can't find a solution how to make it to have a texture. Here's my code:

```
SpringJoint joint;
public GameObject playerCam;
Vector3 grapplepoint;
    private void StartGrapplinghook()
    {
        print("grapple");
        RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(playerCam.transform.position, playerCam.transform.forward, 30f);
        if (hits.Length < 1) return;
        grapplepoint = hits[0].point;
        joint = gameObject.AddComponent<SpringJoint>();
        joint.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
        joint.connectedAnchor = grapplepoint;
        joint.spring = 2.5f;
        joint.damper = 0.25f;

    }
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `LineRenderer` for this, and update its positions every frame if it's enabled.

Make and configure a `LineRenderer` component on the same gameobject the script is on. Explanation for code in comments.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class MyClassName : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    LineRenderer grappleRenderer;   

    SpringJoint joint;
    public GameObject playerCam;
    Vector3 grapplepoint;

    void Awake() 
    {
        // Whatever is already here...

        // If you don't need a fresh grapple copy every time, 
        // create them once here or in the editor and re-use them
        joint = gameObject.AddComponent<SpringJoint>(); 
        joint.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
        joint.spring = 2.5f;
        joint.damper = 0.25f;

        grappleRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>(); 
        grappleRenderer.positionCount = 2; // this could just be set in the inspector

        // Don't use the grapple by default
        joint.enabled = false;
        grappleRenderer.enabled = false;
    }

    private void StartGrapplinghook()
    {
        print("grapple");
        RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(playerCam.transform.position, 
                playerCam.transform.forward, 30f);

        if (hits.Length < 1) return;   

        grapplepoint = hits[0].point;

        joint.enabled = true;
        joint.connectedAnchor = grapplepoint;

        grappleRenderer.enabled = true;
    }

    void StopGrapplingHook()
    {
        // turn off joint and renderer
        joint.enabled = false;
        grappleRenderer.enabled = false;
    }

    // grapple rendering can happen after all other updates finish
    // determining if it should be rendered or not that frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (grappleRenderer.enabled)
        {
            Vector3 grappleStart = transform.position; // or something that makes sense
            grappleRenderer.SetPoints(new Vector3[]{grapplepoint, grappleStart}); 
        }
    }
}
```